# Is reading a NFC chip as a web app possible

Tags: web, nfc

I'd like to use Vaadin to create a web app in Java that reads a NFC chip to identify the user and then proceeds with other options, is that possible?

My reason why I don't want to do that in an android app is to decentralize myself to perform the same work for multiple versions and/or different systems

Comment: If this is possible, the NFC reading part will be done on the client side anyway, so what runs on the backend is not really relevant.

Comment: There [seems to be a Web NFC standard](https://caniuse.com/webnfc) which would enable web applications to interact with NFC tags, but only Chrome for Android supports it for now.

Comment: Here's the draft report for the standard proposal https://w3c.github.io/web-nfc/

Comment: Which browsers do you need to support? This is important, as different browsers offer different amounts of support to new standards, and the answer thus depends on it. You can modify your original question to add this information, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Web NFC API is what you're looking for: https://web.dev/nfc

Web NFC is available **only** on Chrome for Android for now. It is limited to NDEF because the security properties of reading and writing NDEF data are more easily quantifiable. Low-level I/O operations (e.g. ISO-DEP, NFC-A/B, NFC-F), Peer-to-Peer communication mode and Host-based Card Emulation (HCE) are not supported.

Here's a sample for you to play with: https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/web-nfc/

```js
const ndef = new NDEFReader();
await ndef.scan();

ndef.addEventListener("reading", ({ message, serialNumber }) => {
  console.log(`> Serial Number: ${serialNumber}`);
  console.log(`> Records: (${message.records.length})`);
});
```

Comment: Feel free to upvote this answer and let us know what you're going to build ;)

Comment: I'm too new to upvote you but I gave you a checkmark sorry :)